# table data responsive without using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

[my html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBefC.png)

I would like to design a table without using **bootstrap** in that way which should have **margin-right: 0** and when we minimise the window I want the table to display in this way.

[during minimising the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abSU9.png)

```
<div id = "background"></div>
<div class = "header">
    <div class = "headerItems">
        <div class = "items">
            <div class = "items-navigation-back"><i class = "ion ion-arrow-left-c"></i></div>
            <div class = "one"><i class = "ion ion-ios-pulse-strong"></i></div>
            <div class = "two"><i class = "ion ion-speedometer"></i></div>
            <div class = "title"><span class = "title">{{['Device','Doctor','Settings'][0]}}</span></div>
            <div class = "search">
                <input type = "search" ng-model = "searchText" placeholder = "search-items"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "body-content">
    <div class = "bodyItems">
        <div class = "rooms-one">
            <div class = "rooms-one-partone">
                <div class = "rooms-one-partone-icon"><img src = "icons/data/48.png"></img></div>
                <div class = "rooms-one-partone-title"><p>data</p></div>
                <div class = "rooms-one-partone-text"><p>button</p></div>
                <div class = "rooms-one-partone-switch"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
#background{
    right: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
    width: 768px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
.header{
    padding: 3px;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    max-width: 768px;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.headerItems{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.items{
    background: white;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
.navigation-back{
    width: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 35px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
}
.icon-one{
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 35px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.icon-two{
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.search{
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code. It is not clear from your diagrams whether those are individual tables or one single table nor whether the header and footer are part of your table(s).

Comment: im sorry for confusion. only the main contents except header and footer are all tables

Comment: You'll still need to provide some code, illustrating what you've tried so far and highlighting the problems you've encountered.

Comment: okay, i have edited my picture into more understanding and also i have made some coding in

Comment: @Shaggy, i have uploaded the code, please check if need.

Comment: please give suggestions guys

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

table{width:50%;}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {table{width:100%;}}

Comment: i have tried this, thank you but now the problem is actually i have to put some content inside a td like in the first picture.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make fully Responsive Table By Using Following Code

```
     <style>
/* First some padding and borders. */
     table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
    }
    td,th {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 4px 8px;
    }
/* Then some striped rows (nth-child is not supported by IE8).. */
    tbody tr:nth-child(even)  td { background-color: #eee; }


    @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        table {
            overflow-x: auto;
            display: block;
        }
    }
     </style>
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Header 1</td>
        <td>Header 2</td>
        <td>Header 3</td>
        <td>Header 4</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>val 1</td>
        <td>val 2</td>
        <td>val 3</td>
        <td>val 4</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: i have did this but my issue is like to keep equal distances between the tr and td inside a table like i made the first paint picture.